# Transfering facebook profile images into Google Contacts

Tags: facebook, google-contacts

Is it possible to automatically copy the images of people's facebook profile to Google Contacts?

Bonus points if I can also copy other data such as their birthday.

Comment: I know one way that is possible but unfortunately you need the Facebook iPhone app for auto-syncing then iTunes sync across your phone contacts and google contacts. For birthdays you need to go in next direction with Yahoo mail sync and then sync with iTunes, Google Contacts, and your phone. Yes... lots of syncing.. but I did it once and it works well. iTunes and Facebook sync on their own now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a lengthy discussion on the issue:
[Sync/merge Facebook contacts with Gmail contacts](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=058dc912c433f1b8)

I found one app as well:[Google Contact Sync](https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=133934337558&sk=info)

For events/calendar:

[How to Sync Facebook Events with Google Calendar](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/15/how-to-sync-facebook-events-with-google-calendar/)

[Facebook's missing calendar feature](http://www.fbcal.com/):With fdCal get your events and friend's birthdays in Apple iCal, Mozilla Sunbird, Google Calendar, Microsoft Outlook or in your RSS reader! The process can be done in less than a minute, and it's free!